# Getting Average from DATEDIFF Result from the same ID Number

Tags: sql-server

this is my table currently.

[image]

Employees will have multiple order dates and shipped dates. What I want to get is the average of each employee's Diff sum.

Been struggling with how to achieve this.

This is what I have done so far.

```
USE Northwind 

SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID, 
    e.LastName, 
    o.OrderDate, 
    o.ShippedDate, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.ShippedDate) as Diff 
FROM 
    Employees as e 
    JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
```

Comment: thank you Mitch! I was editing the post and then you dropped by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID, 
    AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.ShippedDate) as float)) as AvgDiff 
FROM 
    Employees as e 
    JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
Group By e.EmployeeID
```

If you want more than the `EmployeeId` in the result set, join back like so:

```
select 
    e.EmployeeId
    e.LastName, 
    a.AvgDiff
From
    Employees as e 
Join     (SELECT 
              e.EmployeeID, 
              AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.ShippedDate) as float)) as AvgDiff 
          FROM 
              Employees as e 
              JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
          Group By e.EmployeeID) a ON a.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
```

Comment: this will exclude all NULL rows, am I right? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeID, 
    e.LastName, 
    AVG(1.0 * DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, o.ShippedDate)) as AVGDiff 
FROM 
    Employees as e 
    JOIN Orders as o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
Group by  e.EmployeeID, e.LastName
Order by  e.EmployeeID, e.LastName
```